# Turn table into div

Tags: html, css, html-table

Have this code I want to turn into div, trying to get content to display side by side, but in a div:

```
<table class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">content left</td>
        <td class="style5">content right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try using display: inline-block or float 2 div side by side.. And search before you ask please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it for a fluid layout is to use floating elements wrapped in a container.

```
<div class="style1">
    <div class="style2">Left</div>
    <div class="style5">Right</div>
</div>
```

Assuming a similar tag soup and a fluid layout, css as follows:

```
.style1 {  overflow:auto; position:relative; }
.style2 { float:left; }
.style5 { float:right; }
```

Or if you want them to grid together, make both elements `float:left;`

Answer (score 1):

Ansver of Alan Kael Ball is right, But you can also use "display:table-cell"

[More info about display you can find here!](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: Fine, but link only answers are frowned upon. Links have the bad habit to die and when this happen your answer becomes useless. Try to add some of the content from that link here